# Disable crob job on specifc App Engine instance

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, cron

The situation: I have staging and production apps on App Engine. And I am running back ups for my entities using [Scheduled Backups](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups), which is slightly different from the cron jobs declared by developer. Which means that I am unable to check if it is a staging app or production app before the backup cron is started.

Right now, the only way is to clear the cron.xml manually before deploying to the staging app.

So the question is: is there a better/automated way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have separate branches in your VCS for staging vs. production, you can create your own configuration entry such as CRON_ENABLED, and set it to "true" in the production branch and "false" in the staging branch.  The cron code just checks for CRON_ENABLED and exits if it's not "true".  It's not ideal but it's cleaner than checking for some GAE-specific architectural thing like an instance ID.